# My 60d won't turn on - even with a fully charged battery

Tags: dslr, battery, power

The camera does not power on, even when the battery is fully charged. It is not a battery problem. I have used the battery with other cameras without any problems. The battery indicator on the top LCD only blinks, but the camera does not power on. What could the explanation be?

Comment: Do we talk about Canon EOS 60D?

Comment: When was the last time it had a fully-charged battery in it? If it was a few months, the chances are the backup battery/capacitor needs charging for a few days by the fresh battery before it will work properly. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/54612/57929 [Nikon] and https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/87000/57929 [Canon]

Comment: I think it's been about 5 months. Can I replace the backup battery?

Comment: @Kostk, IMHO you can't. Just put fully charged battery in the camera and do not power it on. Wait for one night and then try to power it on.

Comment: Could be a simple fix, I had a rebel that blew an efuse and acted dead. That repair was under warranty, but it's among the cheapest repairs to out-of-warranty mainstream cameras as well; not turning on doesn't always mean the whole insides are totally fried.